# Card Corner Radius not working in CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement a `cardCornerRadius` to my `cardView` but it does not work with me.

This is my XML:

**EDIT**: I did not mention that I'm adding that `cardView` to a `recyclerView` List so I just resize the `recylcerView` width and height and now it works, but the other problem is when I added the `ImageView` the `cardCornerRadius` not working around the `ImageView`.

Like This:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/journalListImageView"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/quotefancy_work_hard" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/journalTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/journalThoughtsTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Toughts..."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/journalTimestampTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Date created"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can You add screenshot?

Comment: Your code is correct and it's working correctly for me.Try restarting android studio

Comment: add a screenshot to the question

Comment: I have tried your code and no problem is found. Is it caused by a package import error or may i ask what is the error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your code, I'm trying to modify the app:cardCornerRadius="40dp" effect.

You can try rebuilding the project or restarting Android Studio.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The parent layout of cardview, need padding to make card corner & radius effect. Setting margin for cardview is same effect.